# getting average of values across different columns

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a dataframe as shown below. The elements in `col_1` are connected to the elements in `col_2`, giving results in `output_1`. However, some elements in `col_2` are now in `col_1` as well. For example, while `a-->b= 3`, `b-->a= 24`.

```
col_1   col_2   output_1    average
a        b       3            13.5   (because a-->b=3 and b-->a=24)
a        c       5             3.5   (because a-->c=5 and c-->a=2)
a        d       3      
b        a       24     
b        c       12     
b        d       5      
c        a       2      
c        b       3      
c        d       5
```

What i need is to calculate the average of these two values and of course all similar cases across the dataframe.

You can think of the data LIKE THIS: people in `col_1` are calling people in `col_2`. The output is the `duration`. I want to calculate the average duration between every pair of people.  `col_1` and `col_2` have string values while the third column "output" has the numeric values.

I have tried using `pd.merge(df.col_1, df.col_2)` but didn't work. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: can u give ur expected output

Comment: for example: a-->b=3 and b-->a=24. The average is 13.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Column `col_12` you can either drop, or use further as a pair unique key (irrespective to elements order).

```py
print(df)

df["col_12"]=df[["col_1", "col_2"]].apply(lambda x: str(sorted(x)), axis=1)
df2=df.groupby(df["col_12"]).agg({"output_1": "mean", "col_1": "count"}).rename(columns={"output_1": "output_1_mean", "col_1": "rows_count"})

df2.loc[df2["rows_count"]==1, "output_1_mean"]/=2
df2.drop("rows_count", axis=1, inplace=True)
df=df.join(df2, on="col_12")

print(df)
```

And output:

```py
col_1 col_2  output_1
0     a     b         3                                     
1     a     c         5                                     
2     a     d         3                                     
3     b     a        24                                     
4     b     c        12                                     
5     b     d         5                                     
6     c     a         2                                     
7     c     b         3                                     
8     c     d         5

col_1 col_2  output_1      col_12  output_1_mean          
0     a     b         3  ['a', 'b']           13.5          
1     a     c         5  ['a', 'c']            3.5          
2     a     d         3  ['a', 'd']            1.5          
3     b     a        24  ['a', 'b']           13.5          
4     b     c        12  ['b', 'c']            7.5          
5     b     d         5  ['b', 'd']            2.5          
6     c     a         2  ['a', 'c']            3.5          
7     c     b         3  ['b', 'c']            7.5          
8     c     d         5  ['c', 'd']            2.5          
[Program finished]
```

Comment: The code works fine when we have (a-->b) and (b-->a). But, if we only have one-way relationship like (a-->b), it is not dividing the output by 2.

Comment: You mean a->d? So if there's only one way relationship you want it to be divided by 2, and otherwise to take mean of them all, right?

Comment: Yes please, that's what i meant

Comment: Gotcha, I edited my answer- now it should do the trick for you

Comment: OK thank you. Just give me some time to try it. I will update you later about the result.

Answer (score 2):

I would use numpy broadcasting:

```
i,j=np.where((df.col_1+df.col_2).values==(df.col_2+df.col_1).values[:,None])

average=0.5*(df.iloc[i].output_1.reset_index(drop=True)+\
         df.iloc[j].output_1.reset_index(drop=True))

average.index=df.iloc[i].index
df['average']=average
```

The result I got is the following:

```
  col_1 col_2  output_1  average
0     a     b         3     13.5
1     a     c         5      3.5
2     a     d         3      NaN
3     b     a        24     13.5
4     b     c        12      7.5
5     b     d         5      NaN
6     c     a         2      3.5
7     c     b         3      7.5
8     c     d         5      NaN
```

Comment: it is giving me the following error message: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: what's the index of your dataframe? Is it just a normal series of integer like for a standard pandas dataframe?

Comment: the data is a string of numbers. people in col_1 are calling people in col_2. The output is the duration. I want to calculate the average duration between every pair of people.

Comment: Does my solution works if you run the last command without assign it to a new `df` column? (just remove `df['avg']=` and try to run the command)

Comment: Ok, I edited my solution. Check if this is working now.

Comment: I am getting the same error as before. I found sum duplicates in the index when i call "average" alone

Comment: when i run "average" alone, i get values but the index is misleading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201025/discussion-between-baccandr-and-taie).

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

You may try

```py
for ii in a['col_1'].unique():
    p = pd.merge(a[a['col_1'] == ii], a[a['col_2'] == ii], left_on = 'col_2', right_on = 'col_1', left_index = True)
    a.loc[p.index, 'mean'] = p.mean(axis = 1)
```

thanks to @baccandr for the correction

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me. You are just swapping the order of the columns but you are not checking for identity (like `ab==ba` or so).

Comment: mmm, your are partially right. It doesn't work properly, but doesn't just swap the columns, but also makes side by side the a, b and b, a. The problem is that it creates also a lot of useless thing. Checking just the first line of the resulting table was ok, the others not. I will delete the comment and think better the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.mean()`. [click here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) for documentation.

Try this : `df['average']=df[['col_1','col_2']].mean(axis=1)`